# Visual Basic change maker program

Tags: algorithm, vba

I'm working on a program in Visual Basic that takes user input as an integer from 1 to 99 and then tells the use how many quarters, dimes, Nickles, and pennies you need to supplement for that amount. My problem is completely symantical, and my algorithm isn't working like I thought it would. Here is the code that does the actual math, where the variables used are already declared

```
Select Case Input
    Case 25 to 99
        numQuarters = Input / 25
        remainder = Input Mod 25

        Select Case remainder

            Case 10 to 24
                numDimes = remainder / 10
                remainder = remainder mod 10
                numNickles = remainder / 5
                remainder = remainder mod 5

                numPennies = remainder
```

I'm going to stop there, because that's the only part of the code that's giving me trouble. When I enter a number from 88 to 99 (which is handled by that part of the code) the numbers come out strange. For example, 88 gives me 4 quarters, 1 dime, 1 Nickle, and 3 pennies. I'm not quite sure what's happening, but if someone could help me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry about the weird spacing in some of the code, I'm typing this on an iPhone

Comment: are the coin numbers declared as integral types? If not then you need to truncate the result of remainder / X (i.e. `numDimes = Int(remainder/10)` and so on and so forth)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, it worked to an extent, but eventually I just ended up using c# for my program.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon your problem was that it was storing the fractional part of the division, when it should be dropping it and keeping only whole multiples as the fractional portion of each coin is reflected in the remainder.

So after each division, truncate it. E.g.:

```
numQuarters = Int(Input / 25)
remainder = Input Mod 25

'or since you aren't working with fractional currencies you could use integral division operator '\':
numQuarters = Input \ 25
```

With 88 as the input it will, after these lines, have numQuarters = 3 and remainder = 18

Anyway, pehaps a more flexible way that doesn't rely on hard-coded orders of precedence and can handle whatever units you like (cents, fractional dollars, whatever) is like:

```
Sub exampleUsage()

    Dim denominations, change
    Dim i As Long, txt

    'basic UK coins, replace with whatever
    'you can of course use pence as the unit, rather than pounds
    denominations = Array(1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01)
    change = ChaChing(3.78, denominations)
    For i = 0 To UBound(denominations)
        txt = txt & Format(denominations(i), "£0.00") & " x " & change(i) & " = " & Format(denominations(i) * change(i), "£0.00") & vbCrLf
    Next i
    MsgBox (txt)

End Sub

'denominations is a Vector of valid denominations of the amount
'the return is a Vector, corresponding to denominations, of the amount of each denomination
Public Function ChaChing(ByVal money As Double, denominations)
    Dim change, i As Long
    ReDim change(LBound(denominations) To UBound(denominations))
    For i = LBound(denominations) To UBound(denominations)
        If money = 0 Then Exit For 'short-circuit
        change(i) = Int(money / denominations(i))
        money = money - change(i) * denominations(i)
    Next i
    ChaChing = change
End Function
```